# mod_auth_mellon not populating environment variables

Tags: apache, authentication

I have setup mod_auth_mellon for external authentication using SAML 2.0. I get authenticated using an external IdP, but mod_auth_mellon does not populate the environment variables and I am not able to get the username to proceed with the authorization of the resources I want to protect.

The workflow is as follows:
1) user tries to access /test/info.php
2) user gets redirected to external IdP
3) user authenticates against external IdP and gets redirected to /auth/info.php

My mellon configuration is as follows:

```
<Location />
    MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon-config/http_ec2_54_86_69_246.compute_1.amazonaws.com.key

    MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon-config/http_ec2_54_86_69_246.compute_1.amazonaws.com.cert
    MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon-config/http_ec2_54_86_69_246.compute_1.amazonaws.com.xml

</Location>
<Location /auth/info.php>
    MellonEnable "info"
    MellonSetEnv "email" "email"
    MellonSetEnv "username" "username"
    MellonUser "email"
    MellonSamlResponseDump On
    MellonSessionDump On
    MellonVariable "cookie"

</Location>
<Location /test/info.php>
    # This location will trigger an authentication request to the IdP.
    MellonEnable "auth"
    AuthType "Mellon"
    MellonVariable "cookie"
    MellonSetEnv "email" "email"
    MellonSetEnv "username" "username"
    MellonUser "email"
    MellonSamlResponseDump On
    MellonSessionDump On
    MellonEndpointPath /mellon
    Require valid-user

</Location>
```

In auth/info.php, I try to print the $SERVER variable:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
```

I am getting a mellon-cookie but nowhere can I see the values of the environment variables I set.

What configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using apache as a reverse proxy for an app I wanted protected by mod_auth_mellon. It appears apache doesn't automatically  pass headers generated by internal modules. I had to enable mod_headers and add this:

```
RequestHeader set Mellon-NameID %{MELLON_NAME_ID}e
```

This takes the MELLON_NAME_ID header and passes it to the application as Mellon-NameID. You'll have to add similar lines for each header you want passed along, such as MELLON_SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Crunge for your reply

for me it works with following line (Header instead of RequestHeader) and in a `<Location>` section of httpd conf file

`Header set Mellon-NameID: %{MELLON_NAME_ID}e`

(reload of apache service needed)